# Какова этимология слова вернуть (вернуться)?

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова вернуть (вернуться)? Словарь Фасмера отмалчивается по этому поводу. Есть слово "воротить". Есть ли между этими словами родство или они только похожи внешне и по смыслу?

Answer (score 1):

Почему отмалчивается? Просто нужно было смотреть слово вертеть: верте́ть- др. ступени чередования представлены в во́рот, вороти́ть, веретено́.
А вот словарь Цыганенко:
http://lib.co.ua/dict/cyganenkogp/etimologicheskiyslovarrusskogo.txt
ВЕРТЕТЬ "приводить в круговое движение". Праслав. Имеет соответствия
в других и.-е. языках. Сохраняет свое первичное знач.
Звуков, разновидностью  была праслав. форма *vortiti "поворачивать"
(чередов. e/o). Эта форма дала рус. воротить "вернуть", ворочать
"поворачивать", где -оро- из -or-, а ч из tj, и ст.-сл. вращать "вертеть",
где -ра- из -or-, а щ из tj. От глаг.* vbrteti "поворачивать" с пом. суф.
-T}"J- " -ну- образован глагол  вернуть "взятое отдать
(получить) обратно". В нем ь" е, tn " и, -n"j- " -нл- " -ну-. Родственные веретено, верста, ворот, оборот, обратить.

Так что вернуть-воротить-прямые родственники.

Интересны другие исторические соответствия, оказывается,гнездо родственных слов довольно обширно:Вертеть, воротить, вращать, ворочать - вернуть, воротить - ворот, ворота, вратарь - отворить - верёвка -
  вереница - верея - веретено - верста, верстать - сверстник - отверстие - оборот, оборотень - обращение,
  отвращение, извращение - верба - время.